# I am getting this error in magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1, custom-template

error is template file invalid in Magento 2.3.5, so can anyone have idea then please share with me.

Invalid template file: 'Product_SizeChart::size.phtml' in module: 'Product_SizeChart' block's name: 'extra'.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block after="product.info.price" class="Product\SizeChart\Block\Display" name="extra" template="Product_SizeChart::size.phtml" /> 
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: please paste you xml code

Comment: the error message explains it all. the tempalte file is not valid.

Comment: yes i got this error but in my code there is no such code that creates error

Comment: i think calling path is wrong. Please add you template file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing may be to verify the module is active on the site:
by running `php bin/magento module:status`

we need to see this module listed

you need to verify the file named `size.phtml` is within your module folder:

```
<magento_root>/app/code/Product/SizeChart/view/frontend/templates
```

Comment: yes this is right path

Comment: but still it gives error

Comment: error solved finally

Comment: amazing, thanks for your feedback throughout

Comment: ya i am thank full to you because my error has been solved.